# Result of multiple test stages is incorrect

Tags: caffe

I tried to make use of the `test_state` functionality in caffe solver while training. To implement this I added the following code to solver.prototxt

```
test_state: { stage: 'test-on-testSet0' }
test_iter: 726
test_state: { stage: 'test-on-testSet1' }
test_iter: 363
```

Then I modified the train_val.prototxt like this:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
    stage: "test-on-testSet0"
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    scale: 0.0039215684
  }
  image_data_param {
    source: "./set0.lst"
    batch_size: 1
  }
}

layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
    stage: "test-on-testSet1"
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    scale: 0.0039215684
  }
  image_data_param {
    source: "./set0.lst"
    batch_size: 2
  }
}
```

It has to be noted that both the test cases are ideally the same and the test runs on the complete set of images present in the ./set0.lst file.

Still while training using `build/tools/caffe`, the results of the accuracy printed for both the test states are not identical.
The accuracy layers are connected correctly too.
What could be the reason for this mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by using the same `batch_size` for all the test_states. Looks like caffe expects that all the test cases have the same batch_size.

Hope this answer might help someone in the future.

Btw, I guess, this could be issued as a bug to the caffe community. I was facing this issue with the latest commit of caffe (df412ac).